# Building opencv contrib_module on linux

Tags: ubuntu, module, opencv3.0

I am trying to use the Tracking module in https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib. I have used the ccmake and successfully generated and run make -j5 without error. Modules have been built in the build directory but there's no libraries in the /include/opencv2 . In other terms I can't locate the .hpp files generated from the contrib_modules.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the contrib_ module contains some corrupted module that didn't got fixed yet. Luckily the one I need is not. Solved using ccmake and selecting only specific module to build.